# In C Language, What is difference between (name of array) and &(name of array)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int main() {
    int arr[3] = { 1,3,5 };
    int * ptr1 = arr;   
    int * ptr2 = &arr; //  warning C4047: reference level between int * and int (*)[3] is different
    return 0;
}
```

I know '`arr`' means pointer that has starting address value of array '`arr`'. Also, it is a Immutable pointer value. Then, isn't the idea that `'&arr`' is a address of pointer '`arr`', right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but the type differs.

For an array defined like

```
int arr[3] = { 1,3,5 };
```

for most of the cases, `arr` decays to the pointer to the first element in the array, which has the type `int *`, in this case. So, for the statement

int * ptr1 = arr;

the LHS and the RHS are of same type.

On the other hand, `&arr` is a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s, in other words, it's of type `int (*)[3]`. By saying

```
int * ptr2 = &arr;
```

You are trying to assign it to a `int *`. They are not compatible types. Hence the warning.

Comment: I think this answer fits my situation Thank You!!